# Is it possible to run JBoss Fuse 6.3.x PAX-EXAM with JDK 1.8 or JDK1.9?

Tags: jbossfuse, pax-exam

Is it possible to run JBoss Fuse 6.3.x PAX-EXAM with JDK 1.8 or JDK1.9?

I noticed that JBoss Fuse sources set to be compiled with JDK 1.7

Answer (score 0):

based on the Supported compatibility Matrix, it can be executed with JDK 1.8: https://access.redhat.com/articles/310603

Regards,